# Android - how to open image in gallery with delete option

Tags: android, android-intent

I use following code to open an image in the gallery:

```
public void onItemClicked(PictureItem item){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

    Uri imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), "myapp.fileprovider", new File(item.uri.getPath()));

    intent.setDataAndType(imageUri, "image/*");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

This shows my photo in the gallery, but in a 'read-only' mode. I want to be able to delete the image from there, just as if I opened it directly in the gallery.

Which action do I have to use for that? I do not want to use pick, just normal view with the option to delete. I tried `ACTION_EDIT` but it's not supported (and not quite the right choice neither ...).

Comment: Then add the write flag too.

Comment: You should not rely on this .. If you have write external storage privileged then you should use In app Activity to View the file and delete it with user interaction..  `ACTION_EDIT` may not work in All devices ..

Comment: `new File(item.uri.getPath()))` That looks problematic. Please tell the value of uri.getPath() and uri.toString().

Comment: @blackapps how? ´intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);´ doesn't do anything else.

Comment: It depends on item.uri. But if you do not elaborate..

Comment: @blackapps uri toString is this: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/myapp/files/Pictures/LAL334333333_20200416_095822_2732068295251129796.png and getPath is this /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/myapp/files/Pictures/LAL334333333_20200416_095822_2732068295251129796.png

Comment: I think i now know what you want by reading the answer of CommonsWare. So that are the facts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I use following code to open an image in the gallery

First, there are hundreds, if not thousands, of "gallery" apps available for Android.

Second, your code simply asks to view an image (with a broken `Intent` due to your wildcard MIME type). There is no requirement for the app that responds to be a "gallery" app.

> I want to be able to delete the image from there, just as if I opened it directly in the gallery.

Then implement that yourself, in your own app, and get rid of the `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`.

> Which action do I have to use for that?

There is no `Intent` action that says "please display this image, but only if you are a gallery app, and, oh, by the way, you must offer a delete option", which appears to be what you want.

Comment: Thank you, I just wanted to open the image in the default gallery app with the default gallery functions which seems not to be that extraordinary to implement it by myself...

Comment: @Kinaeh: There are ~2.5 billion Android devices, spread over >26,000 device models. There are dozens, if not hundreds, of "default gallery app" implementations across those device models. What the "default gallery functions" are will vary by app. None have to include delete as an option in general, let alone when a third-party app (like yours) starts theirs.

Comment: Okay, I will implement it by myself. It's my very first android app, so I thought there has to be an easy way (I never saw an Android without a gallery with a delete button, and I found out it opened the file manager, not the gallery) ... Thank you. ._.

Comment: @Kinaeh: In general, when you use an "implicit" `Intent` (one with an action string like `ACTION_VIEW`) with `startActivity()`, you could be starting any one of hundreds of possible apps. Some might be pre-installed by manufacturers. Others might be installed by users from the Play Store or elsewhere. In general, we cannot make many assumptions about the behavior of those apps.